# Group related items then merge them and accumulate some properties into arrays

Tags: json, jq

Have a JSON as below,

```
[
  {
    "first": "foo",
    "last": "bar",
    "roll": "32",
    "subject": "maths"
  },
  {
    "first": "joe",
    "last": "mighty",
    "roll": "31",
    "subject": "english"
  },
  {
    "first": "foo",
    "last": "bar",
    "roll": "32",
    "subject": "english"
  },
  {
    "first": "joe",
    "last": "mighty",
    "roll": "31",
    "subject": "maths"
  },
  {
    "first": "foo",
    "last": "bar",
    "roll": "32",
    "subject": "science"
  }
]
```

unique_by(.first,.last, .roll) will remove other subject entries. I want convert 'subject' to an array with all the values in the source JSON array. How to map using jq for creating nested array of subject as below,

```
[
  {
    "first": "foo",
    "last": "bar",
    "roll": "32",
    "subject": ["maths", "english", "science"]
  },
  {
    "first": "joe",
    "last": "mighty",
    "roll": "31",
    "subject": ["english", "maths"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQ doesn't have a nice merge built-in for such tasks yet, but you can achieve this one using `group_by`.

```
group_by(.first, .last, .roll) | map(
  (.[0] | {first, last, roll}) + {subject: map(.subject)}
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oT40ct2-bR)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A variation based on Oguz's excellent answer:

```
  group_by(.first, .last, .roll)
| map( map(.subject) as $subject
     | .[0]
     | {first, last, roll, $subject})
```

Collect related items (group by first, last and roll) and reduce each collection into a single item:

- First we put all subjects into `$subject`
- Take the first item as a "template" but rewrite the `.subject` key with `$subject`.